# Why are defined variables not turning black in Mathematica v10?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I just upgraded Mathematica from version 8 to 10, and I am having a problem with the syntax colouring. Before, when I assigned a value to a variable, it would turn from blue to black to indicate that it was defined. But now, even when I define variables, sometimes they stay blue! However, they still work as expected, meaning that there really is a value assigned to them, and I can call upon it. But why are they coloured incorrectly? It is very confusing to work with as I am not sure if a variable has been defined or not! Some variables still turn black, while others stay blue. I have no idea why this happens for some and not for all.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with Mathematica 11 in Windows 10.

I went with the old "Have you tried turning it off and back on again".

I had to go to the task manager to stop the Mathematica Kernal, but once it reloaded, the variables seemed to start coloring correctly again.